# Slack: how to increase timeout time for loading the data for the Menu with external data source

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-dialog

For the dynamic menu in slack my servers respond back the result in 4-5 second(as there is some computation which will take some time) but it seems like the timeout of the request from slack app is around 3 second and that's why in the drop-down it shows a message "Nothing could be found."
[image]

Is there a way to increase the request timeout time?

Answer (score 3):

The limit for responding to requests from the Slack API is fixed at 3000ms. There's no way to adjust this.